# Safety in nested anonymous functions

Tags: r

I wanted to separate a data frame into a list of data frames using some filtering criteria, so I wrote some code like this

```
library(dplyr)

mySpecies <- iris$Species %>% levels

iris %>%
  function(y) lapply(mySpecies, function(x) filter(y, Species == x))
```

which works fine.

From the perspective of the inner function, "`y`" lives in `parent.env(environment())`, so we can also write

```
iris %>%
  function(x) lapply(mySpecies, function(x) filter(get("x", parent.env(environment())), Species == x))
```

My question is: Is it better to specify the environment of the value we're accessing and can I ever get in trouble if I don't?

Comment: Do you mean to have both function parameters be x in the second example? I'm trying to understand why you might mess with `get`. If you need additional values in the inner function, it would be better to pass them along as parameters to `lapply`

Comment: `split(iris, iris$Species)` seems simpler for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to avoid `get` is possible. How about something like

```
iris %>%
  function(y) lapply(mySpecies, function(x, y) filter(y, Species == x), y=y)
```

Or you might also consider using the `split` function with a friendly wrapper

```
dsplit <- function(x, col) split(x, x[[col]])
iris %>% dsplit("Species")
```

of course the latter will create a group for every species which your first method allows for just extracting subset.